# How to generate a dataframe from a list of n dictionaries generated by n iterations of a loop?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

I've generated a list dictionaries by iterating a function `n` times. Therefore, as a result for `d`, I have `n` dictionaries distincts. This is `d`:

```
 d = {'Insumos' : ["%s" % frame['DESCRIÇÃO'].unique()], 'Valor previsto' : ['%.2f' % y_pred_fut],
                      'MAPE' : [ '%.2f' % mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_mat_val, y_pred)], 
                      'MAE' : ['%.2f' %mean_absolute_error(y_mat_val, y_pred)], 'r2' : ['%.2f' %  r2_score(y_mat_val, y_pred)]}
```

And this is the result for `n` a specific iteration of `d`:

```
{'Insumos': ["['ABUTILOM (ABUTILON STRIATUM)']"], 'Valor previsto': ['30.56'], 'MAPE': ['5.59'], 'MAE': ['1.60'], 'r2': ['-16.70']}
{'Insumos': ["['ACALIFA (ACALYPHA WILKESIANA)']"], 'Valor previsto': ['31.22'], 'MAPE': ['3.24'], 'MAE': ['0.96'], 'r2': ['-2.24']}
{'Insumos': ['[\'ACIONADOR MANUAL TIPO "QUEBRE O VIDRO"\']'], 'Valor previsto': ['72.52'], 'MAPE': ['4.76'], 'MAE': ['3.21'], 'r2': ['-17.48']}
{'Insumos': ["['ADUBO QUÍMICO NPK, 10:10:10']"], 'Valor previsto': ['2.71'], 'MAPE': ['5.02'], 'MAE': ['0.12'], 'r2': ['0.41']}
```

If I apply `pd.DataFrame.from_records(d)`, I get `n` distinct dataframes as below:

```
0  ['ABUTILOM (ABUTILON STRIATUM)']  1.60  5.59          30.56  -16.70
                             Insumos   MAE  MAPE Valor previsto     r2
0  ['ACALIFA (ACALYPHA WILKESIANA)']  0.96  3.24          31.22  -2.24
                                      Insumos   ...        r2
0  ['ACIONADOR MANUAL TIPO "QUEBRE O VIDRO"']   ...    -17.48

[1 rows x 5 columns]
                           Insumos   MAE  MAPE Valor previsto    r2
0  ['ADUBO QUÍMICO NPK, 10:10:10']  0.12  5.02           2.71  0.41
                               Insumos   MAE  MAPE Valor previsto     r2
0  ['ALAMANDA (ALLAMANDA NERIIFOLIA)']  2.13  7.03          32.93  -8.51
                                             Insumos  ...       r2
0  ['ALVENARIA DE EMBASAMENTO - TIJOLOS MACIÇOS C...  ...    -1.83

[1 rows x 5 columns]
.
.
.
```

I want to get all the `n` distinct dictionaries resulting from `n` iterations of `d` and to make a unique dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: What does d actually look like? I don't think it can be a list of dictionaries as stated.

Comment: @user3468054 I just updated it. Take a look! :)

Comment: Still not clear. Do you have a list of these `d` like dicts? If you have d with one like, then you'll get DataFrame with that one line. Are you getting these `d` values in a loop? Show it please.

Comment: @LeonidMednikov yes, I'm getting the d values in a loop. d is a result for n aplication of a function. For i in n I get one line as a dictionary as defined in d. Then I want to get every dictionary item as a line of a unique dataframe.

Comment: @LeonidMednikov ok, I made me think better. That is the problem, d is not a list of dictionary, is a specific dictionart for every interation i. As a print in, the program run n times and produces n dictionaries as shown above. I still don't have a way to solve it. but I think the problem is identified. :)

Comment: @LeonidMednikov I think this is the best formulation of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `from_dict` rather than `from_records` if you have a dictionary.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

If you have multiple input dictionaries, put your dictionaries into a list:

```
d = [
    {'Insumos': ["['ABUTILOM (ABUTILON STRIATUM)']"], 'Valor previsto': ['30.56'], 'MAPE': ['5.59'], 'MAE': ['1.60'], 'r2': ['-16.70']},
    {'Insumos': ["['ACALIFA (ACALYPHA WILKESIANA)']"], 'Valor previsto': ['31.22'], 'MAPE': ['3.24'], 'MAE': ['0.96'], 'r2': ['-2.24']},
    {'Insumos': ['[\'ACIONADOR MANUAL TIPO "QUEBRE O VIDRO"\']'], 'Valor previsto': ['72.52'], 'MAPE': ['4.76'], 'MAE': ['3.21'], 'r2': ['-17.48']},
    {'Insumos': ["['ADUBO QUÍMICO NPK, 10:10:10']"], 'Valor previsto': ['2.71'], 'MAPE': ['5.02'], 'MAE': ['0.12'], 'r2': ['0.41']},
]
```

Then I think it should work as you intend.

```
>>>>pd.DataFrame.from_records(d)
                                        Insumos     MAE    MAPE  \
 0            [['ABUTILOM (ABUTILON STRIATUM)']]  [1.60]  [5.59]
 1           [['ACALIFA (ACALYPHA WILKESIANA)']]  [0.96]  [3.24]
 2  [['ACIONADOR MANUAL TIPO "QUEBRE O VIDRO"']]  [3.21]  [4.76]
 3             [['ADUBO QU?MICO NPK, 10:10:10']]  [0.12]  [5.02]

  Valor previsto        r2
0        [30.56]  [-16.70]
1        [31.22]   [-2.24]
2        [72.52]  [-17.48]
3         [2.71]    [0.41]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You gave the correct answer for the incorrect question. :) I've already fixed it. But anyway I would like to thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

As you feed one `d` to `pd.DataFrame` it can only produce DataFrame with that one line. You need to combine `d` values. The simplest (but not the most efficient) way is to create a `list` and add each calculated `d` in it with `append(d)` like that

```
d_list = []
for some_data in some_data_source:
    d = get_d(some_data)
    d_list.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(d_list)
```

A list of dicts will produce DataFrame like you want.

P.S. And it is not clear, why you embrace one value in a dict like here

```
'MAPE' : [ '%.2f' % mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_mat_val, y_pred)]
```

It would make it difficult to manipulate later. Single value is better to be stored as is

```
'MAPE' : '%.2f' % mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_mat_val, y_pred)
```

And if you want to make some calculations in DataFrame, you'd better not convert the value into string, but store the value. You can convert to string later

```
'MAPE' : mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_mat_val, y_pred)
```

Comment: Hi @LeonidMednikov, that is what I am looking for. However, I'm little confused by the expression "for some_staff". What does it mean? :(

Comment: As I don't know what are you iterating, so just wrote "some_staff", will update to look more like real code